# I changed my system path in system variables, how can I bring it back to what it was?

Tags: windows, command-line, path, environment-variables

I've been trying to unlock my htc device's bootloader and I couldn't get a fastboot command from the cmd to work. I had tried everything and eventually I found this site which said that I just have to change the path in the system variables to `C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;`. I did not save the original one (it was something with ''java'' and ''oracle'', I only remember that). Now it looks like this:

[image]

It didn't help a thing and when I tried to download a torrent, I got an error saying ''The system cannot find the path specified. (WriteToDisk)'' so I assumed I messed something up by altering the path in the system variables.
I'm kinda new to this stuff, please help!

Answer (score 4):

## Option 1: Copy from last known good configuration

Environment variables are stored in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Whenever you shut down Windows successfully, a backup copy of the current control set is created, which is called the "last known good configuration". This is typically stored in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002
```

So, if you have not rebooted since this happened, you should be able to find your old path in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path
```

Just copy that to the **Path** value in the current control set (the key at the top of this post).

**Caveat:**

Typically, **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM** contains **CurrentControlSet**, **ControlSet001**, and **ControlSet002**.  **CurrentControlSet** is actually a pointer to whichever control set is currently being used, which is usually **ControlSet001**, and the last known good configuration is usually **ControlSet002**.

However, this is not *guaranteed* to be the case. You may also have **ControlSet000** and/or **ControlSet003** (maybe even 004 or more, but that's the most I've ever seen). It's also possible that the current control set won't be 001 and the last known good won't be 002.

To be on the safe side, you can check this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Select
```

The value **LastKnownGood** within this key stores the number of the control set that has the last known good configuration. So, if **LastKnownGood** contains the number `0x00000002`, that means that the last known good configuration is in **ControlSet002** (similarly, the value **Current** stores the number of the control set to which **CurrentControlSet** points).

You can find more information about how control sets work in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100010).

---

## Option 2: Copy from the automatic registry backups

If you can't get the old path from the last known good config, all is not lost. Once per week, windows automatically backs up the registry. The backups can be found in this directory:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack
```

The file named **SYSTEM** contains everything in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM** (the system hive). However, retrieving data from this file can be a major pain, because it's locked open while Windows is running (beats my why it needs be constantly open, since it's a backup, but that's the way it is).

Note that **Option 2** is not only a lot more difficult, it also takes away **Option 1**, because it requires you to shut down Windows, and if you do that the last known good config will be overwritten by your current config. So, definitely try **Option 1** first. If you have to resort to the second option, here's how you can do it:

1. Create a system repair disk. To do that, simply open the Start menu and type "system repair" into the search box, then select **Create a System Repair Disc** from the top of the search results.
2. Boot with the repair disk. When you see the `System Recovery Options` wizard, click <kbd>Next</kbd>, then wait for it to search for Windows installations and click <kbd>Next</kbd> again. Under **Choose a recovery tool**, select **Command Prompt**.
3. In the command prompt, find your system drive. C: will be something different, and your system's C: drive will probably be D:. You can check by listing the directory with `dir d:` and seeing if it looks like a Windows installation (has directories named **Program Files**, **Windows**, **Users**, and other stuff). Copy the system hive file somewhere else, for example

   copy D:\Windows\system32\config\RegBack\SYSTEM D:\Temp\SYSTEM_backup_copy

   The destination can be any directory and filename you choose, just make sure you remember where it is.
4. Reboot. You can close the command prompt and click the <kbd>Restart</kbd> button, or simply power cycle the computer.
5. Download [regfileexport](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_file_offline_export.html) and unzip.
6. Open a command prompt and change to the directory where you unzipped regfileexport. Export the copy of the system hive to a text file. Using the locations from my examples, the commands would be:

   ```
   cd \DirectoryWhereYouUnzippedRegfileexport
   regfileexport C:\Temp\SYSTEM_backup_copy C:\Temp\system_hive_backup.txt
   ```

   Again, the destination can be any directory and filename of your choice. The file will be a reg file, but I think it's safer to give it a .txt extension instead of .reg, since you're not planning on exporting it.
7. Open the text file and search for `Session Manager\Environment`. You'll see the key name in brackets. All the values, including **Path**, will be listed underneath it.

Note that **Option 2** is only available if you take action before the next automatic weekly registry backup. To find out when that will happen, just look at the dates of the *most recent* files in the **RegBack** directory and add a week.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and answering to my question! I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I had to restart my pc, therefore I would really like a detailed (for dummies) explanation, how to do the 2. option.

Comment: Or perhaps simply doing a system restore would help?

Comment: Sure, if you have a restore point from before you changed the path, that would work, but that would also reverse any other settings changes, any application installations, and any Windows patches applied since the last restore point. So, I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a recent restore point and haven't made changes since then that you don't want to lose.

Comment: BTW, I know it probably goes without saying after this experience, but when you modify the path, always *add* to the existing path (making sure there's a semicolon between the last directory in the list and whatever you're adding). If someone wrote instructions actually telling you to *change* the path to `C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;` rather than *add* that to the path, they should be dragged into the street and shot. There's no good reason to ever do something like that.